# Keep position of notification alert no matter content css

Tags: css

I have a menu notification I want it to position absolutely.

**PROBLEM**
 If the notification number is `+4` for example, the notification shows properly..
But when is `+45` or `+456` it moves ugly into the center and hides de icon.

**How do I keep the notification alert...always at the right of the trophy icon?**

```css
.menu{
position:relative;
display:block;
width:32px;
height:35px;
background:red;
text-align:center;
margin:100px;
}

.menu img{
width:16px;
height:16px;
padding-top:10px;
}

.trophy_notification{
 position:absolute;
 top:1px;
 right:-1px;
 background: #45A163;
  font-size:11px;
 padding:2px 3px;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
 text-align:center;
  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 z-index:9999;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="menu"><img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/251/251072.svg'/><span class="trophy_notification">+4</span></div>


<div class="menu"><img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/251/251072.svg'/><span class="trophy_notification">+45</span></div>



<div class="menu"><img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/251/251072.svg'/><span class="trophy_notification">+453</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change `right: -1px` into `left: calc( 100% - 10px );` As for right, it will set that the numbers should be at most 1px from the right. By using left, it will set that it should start at 10px from the right, no matter how long the number is.

Comment: `left: calc( 100% - 10px );` is this cross-browser?